# How to parse an object array by JS

Tags: javascript

How do I parse the following object array using JavaScript to get the values **D1**, **S1** etc.?

```
{
 "D1": {
  "C1": {
   "S2": [
    ["P1", "P4"] 
   ],
   "S1": [
    ["P2"]
   ]
  },
  "C2": {
   "S2": [
    ["P3", "P7"]
   ]
  },
  "C3": {
   "S4": [
    ["P6"]
   ]
  }
 },
 "D3": {
  "C3": {
   "S3": [
    ["P5"]
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

**Desired Output**

I need to take out the keys and arrange in the following manner.

```
D1

C1

S2

p1 p4

s1

p2
```

Comment: please describe the real problem, you have. this looks like a follow up of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41736720/how-do-i-parse-the-following-object-array-to-the-following-format-for-displaying) and it looks in isolated view a bit strange. please add, what you have tried. take a look here as well [mcve]

Comment: I have corrected the formatting of this question with an edit. We do not use **Blockqoute** in here when posting outputs of our programs. Please use **Code Sample** button instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, I am printing in the console log, you can push to string array or anything:

```
var data=
{
 "D1": {
  "C1": {
   "S2": [
    ["P1", "P4"] 
   ],
   "S1": [
    ["P2"]
   ]
  },
  "C2": {
   "S2": [
    ["P3", "P7"]
   ]
  },
  "C3": {
   "S4": [
    ["P6"]
   ]
  }
 },
 "D3": {
  "C3": {
   "S3": [
    ["P5"]
   ]
  }
 }
}

getkeys(data);
function getkeys(data){
  for (var key in data){
    console.log(key);
    if(Array.isArray(data[key])){
        for(var i=0;i<data[key][0].length;i++){
          console.log(data[key][0][i]);
      }
    }
    else{
        getkeys(data[key])
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easily, with some use of the `.replace()` and `.match()` string prototypes.

Let's assume `objectArray` in this example is your object in JSON notation.

```
objectArray = JSON.parse(objectArray);
objectArray = objectArray.replace(/[^a-zA-Z1-9 ]/g, "");
objectArray = objectArray.match(/.{1,2}/g);
```

Returns

```
["D1", "C1", "S2", "P1", "P4", "S1", "P2", "C2", "S2", "P3", "P7", "C3", "S4", "P6", "D3", "C3", "S3", "P5"]
```

We now have an array of our strings. This will match as long as you keep going with two characters, otherwise it will fail and you will need a more elegant solution.